# How to parse the next mixed array in swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift

Ok, for clarification, how can I reference cedula: String, codZona: String, departamento: String as properties in this dictionary:

```
["exito": 1, "data": {
     lugarVotacion =     {
         cedula = 75095734;
         codZona = 90;
         departamento = CALDAS;
         direccion = "CL 65 #26-10";
         fecing = "1999-05-24 00:00:00.0";
         mesa = 19;
         municipio = MANIZALES;
         puesto = "UNIVERSIDAD DE CALDAS";
     };
  }
]
```

I have applied JSONSerialization to a server response and got this array as a result:

```
func parseJSON(data: Data) -> [String: Any]? {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
    } catch {
        print("Errror: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Result:

```
["exito": 1, "data": {
  lugarVotacion = {
      cedula = 75095734;
      codZona = 90;
      departamento = CALDAS;
      direccion = "CL 65 #26-10";
      fecing = "1999-05-24 00:00:00.0";
      mesa = 19;
      municipio = MANIZALES;
      puesto = "UNIVERSIDAD DE CALDAS";
    };
  }
]
```

The next step is how to parse cedula, codZona, departamento, dirección, fecing, mesa, municipio, puesto as String variables?

Comment: *This array* is a dictionary.

Comment: What don't you understand about accessing elements of a Swift dictionary? There are countless examples.

Comment: You should improve your question. The code you provide cannot be run in a Playground and it does not state the problem in a coded way. In fact you are pretty vague about what you want to do. StackOverflow will reap amazing answers for questions well described in code, so you should provide an executable version of your problem including the statements that do not work according to your expectations (which you should describe in your comments).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've figured it out. Thanks to @rmaddy for pointing out. Response is a swift dictionary. I've accessed elements this way:

```
guard let datos = lugarVotacion["lugarVotacion"] as? [String: Any] else {
        return
    }
    let puesto = datos["puesto"]
    print(puesto)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly access the elements using the dictionary syntax in Swift or you can use the `Encodable and Decodable` protocols.

You just need to create the following `Struct`:

```
struct LugarVotacion: Decodable {
  let cedula: Int
  let codZona: Int
  let departamento: String \\ I am not sure which kind of class you had used here
  let direccion: String
  let fecing: String
  let mesa: Int
  let municipio: String \\ I am not sure which kind of class you had used here
  let puesto: String
}
```

And add this piece of code to decode:

```
let lugarVotacion = try JSONDecoder().decode(LugarVotacion.self, from: json) // Decoding our data
print(lugarVotacion) // decoded!!!!!
```